# Numbers $n$ whose prime factors are $2$ and $5$ if and only if $\sum_{k=1}^{rad(n)}\mu(k)k=0$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, number-systems, arithmetic-functions

In the literature if defined the arithmetical function $rad(n)$ as $1$ if $n=1$ and for $n>1$ by $rad(n)=\prod_{p|n}p$. It is obviously a **multiplicative function**.  Too we know the **Mobius function** $\mu(n)$ debined by $\mu(1)=1$, $\mu(n)=(-1)^k$ if $n$ is a product of $k$ distinct primes, and is equals to $0$ otherwise.

Two hours ago I had my head in other problem when I've write this nice, really I think that is a nice statement perhaps since our numeric system is based in powers of $2$ and $5$. I believe that isn't obvious. I don't know if this exercise is in the literature.

> **Question.** Prove or refute this statement for integers $n\geq 1$: $n$ is a term of the Sloane sequence **A033846**, **numbers n whose prime factors are 2 and 5**, if and only if $$\sum_{k=1}^{rad(n)}\mu(k)\cdot k=0.$$

**Example.** Let $n=10$ the first term of cited sequence, then

$$\sum_{k=1}^{10}\mu(k)k=1\cdot1-1\cdot2-1\cdot3+0 \cdot4-1\cdot5+11\cdot6-1\cdot7+0\cdot 8+0\cdot 9+1\cdot 10=0$$

I excuse put this question here since I believe that at least one of the implications could be easy for you. Or a counterexample if the conjecture is false. Can your give the details and ensure a nice answer? **Thanks in advance.**

$$\color{red}{\text{Update: There was a mistake in my genuine question. Now the question is rigth. Thanks.}}$$

References:

[1] The On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences, **A033846** Numbers n whose prime factors are 2 and 5.  https://oeis.org/A033846

Comment: You have $1+\mu(k)\geq 0$ for all $k$. Hence if what you have written is the true conjecture, we get $1+\mu(k)=0$ for all $k=1,\cdots,{\rm rad}(n)$

Comment: For $n$ small n=10 is the only solution to $\sum_{k=1}^n   \mu(k)k=0$. This means that $\sum_{k=1}^{\operatorname{rad}(n)}   \mu(k)k=0$, for all the members of the sequence A033846 as they all have $\operatorname{rad}(n) = 10$. The term $\sum_{k=1}^{\operatorname{rad}(n)}   k=0$ seems to be an error.

Comment: Very thanks much @Kelenner, now feel free to give an answer, there was a mstake.

Comment: Muchas gracias @EstebanCrespi, now feel free to give an answer, there was a mstake. I undertand that now you can give a answer to an implication $\to$. I don't know if it is obvious the full statement Please edit your answer. Thanks all users for don't vote up my question, I was disconnected.

Comment: All users, feel free if there are more mistakes, tell me. This question could/should be related with Cloitre's statement (See comments in Solane's page about A033846) when said $\phi(n)=2n/5$, since I compute, of course, the same sequence with a program for $5\phi(n)-2n=0$, and much more quickly.

Comment: $1$ and $10$ are the only values below $10^7$ for which the sum in question is $0$.

Comment: The integer $1$ don't satisfies since $rad(1)=1$: $\mu(1)1=1$. Since $rad(20)=rad(10)=10$ then $\sum_{k=1}^{rad(20)}\mu(k)k=\sum_{k=1}^{rad(10)}\mu(k)k=0$, since I've compute this case $n=10$. And by the words of a previous user reamins all terms $t$ in A033846 then have $rad(t)=10$ since their factors both containg $2$ a $5$, thus $rad(t)=10$ and previous cited sum is zero another time. Thus neccesarly your program should find all term of this sequence. Remains to prove: if $t\in A033846$ then satisfies the *equation*; I will delete this comment in some hours. Very thanks much @Lucian

Comment: Sorry by my words, reamains the implication if $m$ satisfies the *equation* then $m\in A033846$. After I will delete myself nonuseful comments, and edit a new comment with useful facts and reference to the proof of a previous user.